# Image resize runtime process

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

I have a question about Image resize at runtime in php.

I am going to takes a picture from user input, resize it to 3 different size.

1. 160 x 160 --- 10KB
2. 50 x 50 --- 3KB
3. 32 x 32 --- 1.5KB

with 1 million input picture, I need 15GB to store these thumbs.
And also, when I want to show a specific thumbnail, PHP should look into the directory with 1 million thumbs ( for each size ) to find the given image and I have no idea how much process does PHP needs for this so I'm looking for another solution.

I am going to use **[php runtime image resizer](http://joedesigns.com/v22/?page=scripts_widgets&id=67)**. which looks good ( I don't know in my case ).
The question is about performance.

**Looking into a directory with 1 million images takes more process or resizing a 200 x 200 image to 50 x 50 at runtime?**
I want to implement one of these methods on a website with 20.000 visits daily.
Which way is better.

Comment: To be honest, I would not do this with php as you'll might run into max_execution/memory_limits and also for sheer performance reasons. Thought about a shell script with imagemagick or so?

Comment: I've not heard about it before. could you please give me a link.

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/
But it seems that I have misunderstood the question. It really depends  on your filename pattern, what is your file naming? do you need to iterate through the set of files at any point to find the respective image or can you construct the thumb filename in a pattern?

Comment: there is no pattern. names are md5 hash of current time.